# ink! contract upload error

Tags: ink

Trying to upload contract to node via cli but occur error.

```
# Run contract-node 
./target/release/substrate-contracts-node --dev --tmp --ws-external --rpc-cors all

# build contract
cargo contract new flipper
cd flipper
cargo contract build --release

# upload contract
cargo contract upload --suri //Alice


>>> ERROR: Metadata: Node metadata is not fully compatible 
    Caused by:
    Node metadata is not fully compatible


>>> ERROR tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_server::transport::ws: WS transport error: i/o error: Transport endpoint is not connected (os error 107); terminate connection: 5
```

Comment: Is `substrate-contracts-node` running in the background?

Comment: update to latest version now working well, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the versions (check the pallet-contracts version of your substrate-contracts-node ).
From [this issue](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/616) on the cargo-contract repository.

> The "Node metadata is not fully compatible" means that the instantiate call is not compatible with the version of pallet_contracts you are using.

You can check the substrate documentation guide: [Prepare your First Contract](https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/smart-contracts/prepare-your-first-contract/) to see how to update your environment to the latest versions.

For cargo-contract

```
cargo install --force --locked cargo-contract --version 2.0.0-rc
```

Check the version of the pallet_contracts in your node, but if you are using the template contracts node, update it with:

```
cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --tag <latest-tag> --force --locked
```

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: I'm facing the same issue while running latest version, how did you resolve it?

Comment: updated the answer!

Comment: hi Daan Sorry for the delay in getting back to you. I have reinstalled all involved libraries and nodes and rebuilt. I put in the latest versions of everything. Then it was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I got a similar error `ERROR tokio-runtime-worker jsonrpsee_server::transport::ws: WS transport error: i/o error: Transport endpoint is not connected (os error 107); terminate connection: 0`.
It happened when running Substrate Contracts Node using the latest [contracts-ci-linux](https://github.com/paritytech/scripts/blob/master/dockerfiles/contracts-ci-linux/Dockerfile) Dockerfile that I reported [here](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/1108) before discovering this post, which uses the latest commit in the 'master' branch of the "cargo-contracts" repo [here](https://github.com/paritytech/scripts/blame/master/dockerfiles/contracts-ci-linux/Dockerfile#L61) and the latest commit in the 'main' branch of the "substrate-contracts-node" repo [here](https://github.com/paritytech/scripts/blame/master/dockerfiles/contracts-ci-linux/Dockerfile#L65).

So that was using Substrate Contracts Node version `substrate-contracts-node --version` of `substrate-contracts-node 0.25.0-a2b09462c7c`
and Cargo Contract version `cargo contract --version` of `cargo-contract-contract 2.2.1-7253c6a-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.

I resolved the error by just following https://use.ink/getting-started/setup instructions and updating the Dockerfile so it would install a specific older version substrate-contracts-node (instead of its latest commit) with `cargo install contracts-node --git https://github.com/paritytech/substrate-contracts-node.git --tag v0.23.0 --force --locked` and by installing the latest stable version of Cargo Contract cargo-contract (instead of the latest commit) with `cargo install cargo-contract --version 2.2.1` as shown in my commit [here](https://github.com/ltfschoen/InkTest/commit/1edf0b5fd6ebb5f361de758127a8dc70028feef9#diff-f34da55ca08f1a30591d8b0b3e885bcc678537b2a9a4aadea4f190806b374ddc).